# How to get the unread count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I created my message schema as following:-

```
{ 
_id : message_unique_id,
recipients : [ user_id1,user_id2,user_id3 ],
message : "Hello Word",
readBy : [user_id2,user_id3],
chatId : unique_id_for_every_chat
}
```

Now i am able to get the last message of each conversation, but not able to get the count of unread messages. What i am using is as following:-

```
Messages.aggregate([
{ $match : {recipients : {$in : [my_user_id]},
{ $project : {
chatId : 1,
recipients : 1,
readBy : 1
}, { $group : {
_id : "$chatId",
message : "$last" : "$message"} }}]).exec();
```

The above query works good and return the last message of each chat done by the user. But now i want to get the unread message count too. I used the following query:-

```
Messages.aggregate([
    { $match : {recipients : {$in : [my_user_id]},
    { $project : {
    chatId : 1,
    recipients : 1,
    readBy : 1,
    unread: {  
            $cond: { if : { "$readBy" : {$in : [my_user_id]}}, then : 
            0, else : 1 }
        }
    }, 
    { $group : {
          _id : "$chatId",
           unreadCount : { $sum: "$unread" },   
           message : "$last" : "$message"} }}]).exec();
```

But this query returns null. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $project read value with below:

```
 unread: {$cond: {
            if: {$gte: [{$indexOfArray: ["$readBy", my_user_id]}, 0]}, then: 0, else: 1
         }}
```

try

```
 unread: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            "$setIsSubset": [
              [my_user_id],
              "$readBy"
            ]
          },
          then: 0,
          else: 1
        }
      }
```

This worked in my case.

Comment: It give error. MongoError : invalid operator '$indexOfArray".

Comment: I think i need to upgrade the version to use this. Right now the version is 3.2.22

Comment: i've added new code with fixed $in, can you try that